# Is BigQuery appropriate for small datasets?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dataset

I have to host a small (empty, 100MB per year growth) analytic-based dataset and was searching for a managed solution with low costs and *no* administration burden.

Bigquery seems to fit my needs in terms of data ingestion and query capabilities, however all the usage examples cite multi-GB to PB datasets.
Is there a performance or monetary catch to using BQ for small datasets?

Thanks

To reiterate, the pros of BQ for me would be:

- no sysadmin/maintenance required whatsoever, can run for years without babysitting
- linear scaling costs, starting from pennies
- integration with datastudio

Answer (score 5):

There is no monetary catch to using BQ for small datasets.

Expect for your queries a minimum of 2-3 seconds even for small datasets, if you can deal with that, BQ is a good choice.

Comment: Just to add: you should keep in mind the quotas for concurrent queries in a project on a table, if you plan to connect datastudio directly. Dashboards can cause a lot of queries - depends of course: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas